# How to save scroll bar values using sharedPreferences in android

Tags: android, sockets, arduino, sharedpreferences

How could I change the value of a variable using sharedPreferences to update a string and pass it to Arduino using Socket.
I am using inputStremBuffer and outputWriter, I just want to update the value of a variable and pass it to server to perform operations (e.g. Light On/Off and intensity control)

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_entry_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Rel12345"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/temerature_show"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Rome Temerature"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temerature_show"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:hint="temp value"
            android:id="@+id/temerature_value"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Light 1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temerature_value"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/light1"
            />
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/toggleButton"
            android:scrollbarSize="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:background="@drawable/light_button_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temerature_value"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            />
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbarlight1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/light1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlight1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekbarlight1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Send"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Light 2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlight1"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/light2"

            />
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/toggleButton"
            android:scrollbarSize="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:background="@drawable/light_button_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlight1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbarlight2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/light2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlight2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekbarlight2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Send"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fan"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlight2"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/fan"

            />
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/toggleButton"
            android:scrollbarSize="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:background="@drawable/fan_button_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlight2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbarlight3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fan"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlight3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekbarlight3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Send"
            />
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/toggleButton"
            android:scrollbarSize="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:background="@drawable/motion_button_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlight3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motion Sensor"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlight3"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/motion"/>
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/toggleButton"
            android:scrollbarSize="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:background="@drawable/temerature_button_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/motion"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temerature Sensor"
            android:layout_below="@+id/motion"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/temeraturetext"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: To save information to `SharedPreferences`, you'll need to write some code in your activities (and not xml). Have you written any code? What problem have you got?

Comment: done! now i got it how to do it...